# Selenium Webdriverjs find text string using loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

Ok, this is getting annoying.  I've been trying to work this out for 4 days now and I am just stuck.  I need to click on a button, but the button has no ID or class attribute.  I think the only approach is to loop through all "Button" objects and find the one  containing the text "Submit".  And then click on that element.  But thanks to the Async nature, once you find the button object, you can't get that object.  I need some way to step back, or pass that object as part of the "innerHTML" function call.  Here is where I am at:

```
driver.findElements(webdriver.By.tagName('button')).then(function(webElements) 
{
    for(var i=0; i<webElements.length; i++)
    {
        driver.executeScript(function() {
            return webElements[i].innerHTML;
        }).then(function(innerHTML) {
             if(innerHTML == 'Submit')
                 webElements[i].click();   // webElements[i] is NULL
        });                
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could locate the button via a CSS selector instead e.g.

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css("input[type=submit]")).click();
```

or by text value, if necessary:

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css("input[value='Submit']")).click();
```

Comment: There are too many other Submit buttons and no IDs to isolate the button I need to click

Comment: @user3508995 I presume you can't take the nth element (e.g. 3rd form) to do your selection?